# Trying to understand proof that price of anarchy O(logm/loglogm) for m links

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Let $t \geq \dfrac{3\ln m}{\ln\ln m}$ where $m$ is a positive integer.

I'm trying to see why:

$$t + \sum_{\tau = t}^\infty m\cdot\left(\dfrac{2e}{\tau}\right)^\tau \leq t + \sum_{\tau = t}^\infty 2^{-\tau} \leq t + 1$$

I don't see it. Also, do we need the $m$ for this equation to be true?

http://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/~czumaj/PUBLICATIONS/DRAFTS/SODA-2002-Full.pdf

See right above theorem 4

Comment: Are you sure we have $t$ on both sides of the inequality? We could just remove it, no? Also is $t$ an integer? By its definition above I'm not sure but if $t$ is not a positive integer what is the meaning of summing $\tau$ starting from $t$? I fear we may have several typos in the question itself.

Comment: for the purposes of answering this, then yes we can remove it. Just as a note, for the whole proof to work we will want the t.Finally, t is defined at the top.

Comment: You have a serious typo: if you read the paper (Theorem 4) $t\ge \dfrac{3\ln(m)}{\ln(\ln(m))}$ and **not** $t=\dfrac{3\ln(m)}{\ln(\ln(m))}$.

Comment: @SergioParreiras Thanks. Fixed.

Comment: There is some manipulations here:
$$t+\sum_{\tau=t}^{+\infty}m\cdot\bigg(\frac{2e}{\tau}\bigg)^\tau\leq t+\sum_{\tau=t}^{+\infty}2^{-\tau}\iff \sum_{\tau=t}^{+\infty}m\cdot\bigg(\frac{2e}{\tau}\bigg)^\tau\leq \sum_{\tau=t}^{+\infty}2^{-\tau}\iff$$

$$\iff \sum_{\tau=t}^{+\infty}m\cdot\bigg(\frac{2e}{\tau}\bigg)^\tau - \sum_{\tau=t}^{+\infty}2^{-\tau}\leq0\iff \sum_{\tau=t}^{+\infty}m\cdot\bigg(\frac{2e}{\tau}\bigg)^\tau - 2^{-\tau}\leq0\iff$$

Comment: $$\iff \sum_{\tau=t}^{+\infty}\frac{m\cdot2^\tau e^\tau}{\tau^\tau}- \frac{1}{2^\tau}\leq0\iff \sum_{\tau=t}^{+\infty}\frac{m\cdot2^{\tau} e^\tau\cdot2^\tau-\tau^\tau}{\tau^\tau2^\tau}\leq0\iff$$

$$\iff \sum_{\tau=t}^{+\infty}\frac{m\cdot(4 e)^\tau-\tau^\tau}{(2\tau)^\tau}\leq0$$

Comment: I'm not sure if you can solve from this, but looks simpler then the original one.

Comment: Is m a constant? (the 'm' before the $(4e)^\tau$)

Comment: This is the same m you defined, its a positive integer.

Answer (score 2):

This is really not an answer but I hope someone can use my work to come-up with one.

I don't know how to compute $\sum\limits_{\tau=t}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{2e}{\tau}\right)^\tau$ so my idea was to compare the two series term by term:
$$ m\cdot \left(\frac{2e}{\tau}\right)^\tau \le 2^{-\tau} \Leftrightarrow m\cdot \left(\frac{4e}{\tau}\right)^\tau \le 1 \Leftrightarrow \ln(m)+\tau\cdot\left(\ln(4)+1-\ln(\tau)\right)\le 0.\tag{1}$$

We also have the condition: $$\tau\ge t \ge \frac{3\ln(m)}{\ln(\ln(m))}.\tag{2}$$

If we can prove that (2) implies (1) for all $m$, we would have answered the question.

Now $\tau\cdot\left(\ln(4)+1-\ln(\tau)\right)$ increases before its unique maximum at $\tau=4$ and  decreases afterwards. On the other hand: $\frac{3\ln(m)}{\ln(\ln(m))}$ has its unique minimum, which is $3e$, at $e^e$. We can conclude that $\tau\cdot\left(\ln(4)+1-\ln(\tau)\right)$ is always decreasing in $\tau$ in the range of interest as $\tau>3e>4$.

The practical consequence of the above is that now it suffices to prove that (1) holds for $\tau=\frac{3\ln(m)}{\ln(\ln(m))}$. But the plot of $\ln(m)+\frac{3\ln(m)}{\ln(\ln(m))}\left(\ln(4)+1-\ln\left(\frac{3\ln(m)}{\ln(\ln(m))}\right)\right)$ lies below zero only for $m\le 4$.

Assuming I didn't do mistakes, the above shows that comparing terms by terms only works for $m\le 4$.

Comment: I was mistaken regarding the bound. I do, however, like to add that if you compose an answer intending for other members to pitch in, I believe the community wiki mode was made for it (it requires a much lower reputation to edit the post, and doesn't award reputation to encourage others to participate on your answer).

Comment: @JonathanY. Thanks: now it is a community wiki.

Comment: For $m$ large enough, your term should be negative as well. The largest order terms are $\ln(m)+\frac{3\ln(m)}{\ln\ln m} \left( -\ln(\ln m)+O(\ln \ln \ln m)\right)=-2\ln m+o(\ln m)$, unless I'm mistaken.